# How to align a link in the middle of a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, styled-components

I have been struggling with adding a link with the text 'here' to flow inline with the entire paragraph.
Essentially what I would like to do is

'Gibberish **here** detailing the required steps.'

How can I accomplish this so as to have everything in a single line? I have tried doing this but it gives me the results attached in the screenshot.

```
          <Flex direction="column" gap="s">
          GIBBERISHH{" "}
          <Anchor
            href=""
            trackingId=""
            label="Read the Walkthrough"
          />
          detailing the required steps.
        </Flex>
```

[image]

Edit: Also tried changing the Flex direction to a row but I get this result which is not what I need either. Any suggestions would be great!

[image]

Comment: the direction of the flex is `column` change it to `row` and everything will come in a line

Comment: @mrtechtroid updated my post with the row direction. I tried that as well and does not work.

Comment: How is your anchor component defined

Comment: What do you mean? @DanielA.White

Comment: Why do you have the everything wrapped in <Flex> if you want them inline ? Just wrap in a <p> tag or a <div>

Comment: just overcomplicating things @WiseCode. thanks. i feel dumb right now lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a "p" tag if it's a paragraph:

```
    <p>
          GIBBERISHH{" "}
          <Anchor
            href=""
            trackingId=""
            label="Read the Walkthrough"
          />
          detailing the required steps.
    </p>
```

Comment: thanks. <p> or a <div> works great!

Comment: Maybe accept his answer if it solved your problem. @TanDev